# Scafolded controller class trigger invalidoperationexception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I was trying to learn some web api part. So created an EF and then created a controller using DB context. Here is the controller .net generated for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SanApi.Models;

namespace SanApi.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TblDepartmentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ClassooContext _context;

    public TblDepartmentsController(ClassooContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/TblDepartments
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TblDepartmentMaster>>> GetTblDepartmentMaster()
    {
        return await _context.TblDepartmentMaster.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/TblDepartments/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TblDepartmentMaster>> GetTblDepartmentMaster(int id)
    {
        var tblDepartmentMaster = await _context.TblDepartmentMaster.FindAsync(id);

        if (tblDepartmentMaster == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return tblDepartmentMaster;
    }

    // PUT: api/TblDepartments/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutTblDepartmentMaster(int id, TblDepartmentMaster tblDepartmentMaster)
    {
        if (id != tblDepartmentMaster.DepartmentId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(tblDepartmentMaster).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!TblDepartmentMasterExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/TblDepartments
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TblDepartmentMaster>> PostTblDepartmentMaster(TblDepartmentMaster tblDepartmentMaster)
    {
        _context.TblDepartmentMaster.Add(tblDepartmentMaster);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetTblDepartmentMaster", new { id = tblDepartmentMaster.DepartmentId }, tblDepartmentMaster);
    }

    // DELETE: api/TblDepartments/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TblDepartmentMaster>> DeleteTblDepartmentMaster(int id)
    {
        var tblDepartmentMaster = await _context.TblDepartmentMaster.FindAsync(id);
        if (tblDepartmentMaster == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.TblDepartmentMaster.Remove(tblDepartmentMaster);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return tblDepartmentMaster;
    }

    private bool TblDepartmentMasterExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.TblDepartmentMaster.Any(e => e.DepartmentId == id);
    }
}
}
```

But its triggering an error saying

> nvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'SanApi.Models.ClassooContext' while attempting to activate
>   'SanApi.Controllers.TblDepartmentsController'.

I havent got an idea since its auto generated and where the error is. I am very new to Web API. So got stucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the database context like :

```
public class ClassooContext : DbContext
{
    public ClassooContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

}
```

You need to register the `ClassooContext` . ASP.NET Core implements dependency injection by default. Services (such as the EF database context) are registered with dependency injection during application startup. To register `ClassooContext` as a service, open `Startup.cs`, and add the highlighted lines to the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddDbContext<ClassooContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And open the `appsettings.jso`n file and add a connection string like :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

Then you can inject to controller to use the EF context like :

```
private readonly ClassooContext _context;

public TblDepartmentsController(ClassooContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome man.. But just thinking why VS not adding that automatically since its important/must have for the auto generated controller to work